# Programmatically ensure random color palette is vibrant and distinct from background

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, colors

Okay, I have a Qt GUI application where I have decided to generate the colour palette randomly (allowing me to distinguish data displayed based on the data's unique ids).

The algorithm I use is as thus:

```
void Palette::generatePalette(quint32 seed, bool dark) {
    sfmt_t sfmt;
    sfmt_init_gen_rand(&sfmt, seed);
    quint32 i;
    qreal hue;
    QColor col;

    qreal lightness = 0.75;
    qreal saturation = 0.6;

    if (dark) {
        lightness = 0.5;
        saturation = 0.8;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfColors; i++) {
        hue = sfmt_genrand_res53(&sfmt);
        hue += 0.618033988749895;
        hue = fmod(hue, 1.0);
        col = QColor::fromHslF(hue, saturation, lightness);
        palette.append(col);
    }
}
```

This gives me, for the most part, nice pastel colours which are very visible against the grey background. However, occasionally, a yellow comes out which is not easily distinguishable from the background.

What I would like to know is, whether it is possible to programmatically compare the background colour with the generated colour and if it is too indistinguishable, to then discard and regenerate the colour.

I have looked around on google for an answer but I cannot find one. I am not usually a GUI programmer, either, so I don't work with colour in this way that often.

Comment: Yes it's possible to do. I'm thinking this is more in the area of color theory, and maybe reading up on how colors work would offer you the insights you need to come up with a nice algorithm.

Comment: In general, this might be a bit tricky, but for your particular case, since your only random variable is hue, I would just determine the range of hues that you find acceptable by inspection and limit your code to choose a hue in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several [color distance/difference methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).

For your application (since you do not require big accuracy) you could use the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) (or another norm in a color metric space), and if this distance is below a threshold you will drop the color.

```
double colorRGBEuclideanDistance(const QColor& c1, const QColor& c2)
{
    return sqrt(pow(c1.red()-c2.red(), 2) +
                pow(c1.green()-c2.green(), 2) +
                pow(c1.blue()-c2.blue(), 2));
}
```

Comment: Euclidean distance in RGB-space is not very good, as the light grey and the bright yellow from Luke's example will have a large distance, but will be hard to tell apart. It's better to use a perceptional color model, like the CIE ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses#CIE

Comment: I totally agree, from my experience CIELAB gives optimal results. The RGB distance was given just for an example

Comment: @pnezis Thanks. I converted to CIELAB and calculated the euclidean distance in that colourspace. Interestingly, it seems that the yellow-grey distance was greatest, so I simply made my threshold an upper threshold. Seems to have done the trick. However, now I have shrunk the number of acceptable colours and so some are being produced twice which is not ideal at all.